# “settings.DATABASES is improperly configured” error performing syncdb with django 1.9

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine, database

I start a tutorial for Django 1.9 and I want to use Mongoengine for my database .. when I tried migrate the DB "CMD: *python manage.py migrate*" I had this error

*[  raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details. ]*

My code : settings.py

```
import os
from mongoengine import *

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '3x80*9(7bdeg^lps-go9a8(@x_vmk#5vj66d9l0t3js(vknq(i'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mongoengine',
    'TestApp'
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'testMongoDB.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'testMongoDB.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

connect('myDB',username="NOUH",password="123456" )

SESSION_ENGINE = 'mongoengine.django.sessions'
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'mongoengine.django.sessions.BSONSerializer'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy'
        }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

any ideas ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

You didn't configure the DATABASES in the settings.py file correctly. Instead of adding it in the INSTALLED_APP, you need DATABASE configuration settings.

Configuration

```
DATABASES = {
   'default' : {
      'ENGINE' : 'django_mongodb_engine',
      'NAME' : 'my_database'
   }
}
```

Django MongoDB Engine also takes into account the HOST, PORT, USER, PASSWORD and OPTIONS settings.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest possible settings file is for a single-database setup using SQLite. This can be configured using the following:

> DATABASES = {
>       'default': {
>           'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
>           'NAME': 'mydatabase',
>       } }

see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases